# What is `it` here in the code?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

I'm reading the following [blog](https://davidwalsh.name/async-generators).

They have the code in the blog:

```
function request(url) {
    // this is where we're hiding the asynchronicity,
    // away from the main code of our generator
    // `it.next(..)` is the generator's iterator-resume
    // call
    makeAjaxCall( url, function(response){
        it.next( response );
    } );
    // Note: nothing returned here!
}
```

The code seems easy. But in `makeAjaxCall` callback, they have a line called `it.next(response)`. What is this `it`? I know they are telling its coming from generators, but I don't see it being passed anywhere!

But they do this:

```
function *main() {
    var result1 = yield request( "http://some.url.1" );
    var data = JSON.parse( result1 );

    var result2 = yield request( "http://some.url.2?id=" + data.id );
    var resp = JSON.parse( result2 );
    console.log( "The value you asked for: " + resp.value );
}
```

How come this line:

```
var result1 = yield request( "http://some.url.1" );
```

works if `it` is undefined in `request` function?

Comment: Its an `Iterator`. You must have defined it somewhere else

Comment: `// it.next(..) is the generator's iterator-resume
    // call` so `it is the generator's iterator`

Comment: `it` is defined in the exact same code block. `var it = main();`

Comment: @batman, did you [find it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40501765/2545680)?

Answer (score 0):

`it` is a generator and it's defined in your blog post at the bottom:

```
var it = main();
it.next(); // get it all started
```

Answer (score 0):

From that same author in that blog that you said, there is a previous post that explains the basics for ES6 Generators. You can find the previous post [here](https://davidwalsh.name/es6-generators/). And about your question, he defines it, in that same post, in the first paragraphs like this:

```
function *foo() {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
    yield 4;
    yield 5;
}

var it = foo();
```

You should read that post, it explains everything step by step :)

Answer (score 0):

Full example on the page:

```
function request(url) {
    // this is where we're hiding the asynchronicity,
    // away from the main code of our generator
    // `it.next(..)` is the generator's iterator-resume
    // call
    makeAjaxCall( url, function(response){
        it.next( response );
    } );
    // Note: nothing returned here!
}

function *main() {
    var result1 = yield request( "http://some.url.1" );
    var data = JSON.parse( result1 );

    var result2 = yield request( "http://some.url.2?id=" + data.id );
    var resp = JSON.parse( result2 );
    console.log( "The value you asked for: " + resp.value );
}

var it = main();
it.next(); // get it all started
```

`it` is an `iterator` - (`main` function).

Reference link about [Iterators and generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators).

Example about iterators:

```
function makeIterator(array){
    var nextIndex = 0;

    return {
       next: function(){
           return nextIndex < array.length ?
               {value: array[nextIndex++], done: false} :
               {done: true};
       }
    }
}

var it = makeIterator(['yo', 'ya']);
console.log(it.next().value); // 'yo'
console.log(it.next().value); // 'ya'
console.log(it.next().done);  // true
```